# How to attach an HTML jpeg to email?

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook, jpeg

I utilize Excel to mass mail clients. My VBA code can't locate the HTML jpeg for the advertisement.

Is the imgur link not good or is it my code?

```vb
MailWindows()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "insert here"
.Attachments.Add Fname, 1, 0
                .HTMLBody = "<img src=""cid:"https://url.jpeg height=1650 width=1275>"
                .Display  
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Check your quotes. See where the code here turns orange?

Comment: Please, try `"<img src=""cid:"https://url.jpeg"" height=1650 width=1275>"`, and try to define `Fname`, which should be somehow  correlated to the `cell` range (maybe in the following cell on the same row). Besides that, it is not good (even accepted by VBA) to use `Dim cell As Range`. `cell` has a clear meaning for VBA and you, or somebody else, may be confused when debugging, if the code becomes more complex. Try using `Dim cel As Range`, for instance...

Comment: Didn't the above suggestion solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you. It and Dmitry's solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the quote problems, you are referring to an image through cid (content-id), which means the email client must look for an attachment in the same message with the Content-ID MIME header set to `https://url.jpeg`.

If you meant to refer to an external image, it needs to be

```
.HTMLBody = "<img src=""https://url.com/someimage.jpeg"" height=1650 width=1275>"
```

If you refer to an embedded  image, you need to actually add the attachment and set `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property appropriately using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`

Comment: Dmitry, Thank you so very much for the solve. I cant believe I forgot .jpeg and I am learning this all very adamantly.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your assistance!

Comment: @DavidZubick - if the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you!